# automatic test template generation?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing

there is some mechanist that given some module, like for example

```
#N.py

__all__=["a", "b", ...]

def a(...):
    ...

def b(...):
    ...

...
```

create a template for unittest like for example

```
#test_N.py
import unittest
import N

class Test_N(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_a(self):
        self.fail("Not implemented Test")

    def test_b(self):
        self.fail("Not implemented Test")

    def test_...

    ...
```

such thing or something similar exist? or I have to do it myself?

Comment: This doesn't seem like a very intuitive thing to do. Part of the *art* of putting together good unit tests is naming your test methods appropriately. Can you share what problem you are looking to solve here exactly?

Comment: @idjaw well I have module which have several sub-modules, and each one with several function, I want to create a unit test for each function in each module, and having such template would be great to me as it save me for write the same thing too many times and focus only in the detail I want to test in those functions...